# What is the type of a Sidekiq Job ID?

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

I'm looking to store the sidekiq job ID in the database so that I can use it later (to delete and/or reschedule the job), but I can't find the type of the ID so I can use the correct column type in the migration.

What's the data type of a Sidekiq Job ID? Int? UUID? String?

Comment: Can you please clarify some things for me? Did you endeavor to store the attribute in a database column without first finding an example of the attribute? And despite knowing that you have the need to store this attribute, was your first stop asking on StackOverflow without doing any form of independent research?

Comment: The source code makes it clear that the default implementation is a `SecureRandom.hex(12)` but you can technically override this (**which would not be recommended**)

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks! Do you happen to remember which source files had that code? It'd be nice to provide it as a link in my answer. (No worries if you don't, I can track it down too). Oh! Also, if you answer, I'll mark it accept it so you can get the karma :)

Comment: https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/blob/4c101d243e9589cd3d1a81060dac602beb1652a1/lib/sidekiq/client.rb#L124, https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/blob/404827ab778a6a9736d2ce0b1b3cf5def9bf2152/lib/sidekiq/job_util.rb#L54, https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/blob/4c101d243e9589cd3d1a81060dac602beb1652a1/lib/sidekiq/transaction_aware_client.rb#L15

Answer (score 0):

@engineersmnky found the answer in the source code; default is `SecureRandom.hex(12)`